# Creating python loop to shorten the length of turtle graphics code

Tags: python-3.x, turtle-graphics

Below is my code for drawing a house using the turtle graphics. I need help in creating a for loop in order to shorten the length of the code.

```
import turtle   

wn = turtle.Screen()   

wn.bgcolor("Blue")

house = turtle.Turtle()  

house.color("Yellow")

house.pensize(5)

house.speed(1)

house.left(45)   

house.forward(141)

house.left(135)      

house.forward(100)

house.left(135)

house.forward(141)

house.left(135)            

house.forward(100)       

house.left(45) 

house.forward(71) 

house.left(90) 

house.forward(71)

house.left(45) 

house.forward(100)    

house.left(90)

house.forward(100) 

wn.mainloop()

yellowHouse()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put the lengths and angles in an array and loop over that like so:

```
import turtle   

wn = turtle.Screen()   

wn.bgcolor("Blue")

house = turtle.Turtle()  

house.color("Yellow")
house.pensize(5)
house.speed(1)

angles = [45, 135, 135, 135, 45, 90, 45, 90]
lengths = [141, 100, 141, 100, 71, 71, 100, 100]

for i in range(len(angles))
    house.left(angles[i])   
    house.forward(lengths[i])

wn.mainloop()

yellowHouse()
```